# Raspberrypi4 blocks incoming network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, raspberry-pi

I have an issue which I can't understand. I have one RPI4 that is connected via wifi, and I can access it over ssh for some time after I reboot it. However at some point (don't know exact time, might be couple hours or it might be couple days) it stops responding completely, neither ssh, nor ping can access it - request timeout. I have another RPI4 that is connected directly to router via cable (pihole) and for some reason, that is the only device that can access that other inaccessible RPI4. How can I debug what is going on and prevent it from happening?

In other words: there is an ISP provided router and two rpi4. One (A) is connected via cable, another (B) via wifi. After some time (B) stops responding to ssh/ping, but for some weird reason I can access it from (A) via ssh/ping, but not from any other wifi connected device. I am using IP addresses to access them.

Comment: I am using IP addresses.

Comment: Have you updated your Raspberry Pi 4 ? `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt install firmware-brcm80211` ? And another is that RPi4 doesn't have 5GHz, so try disabling the 5GHz band in your router if your SSID is the same for 2,4 and 5 GHz.

Comment: Yes, it is up to date and firmware-brcm80211 is installed. Though I don't understand why this would change anything, wifi is working, I can download things to RPI4 and I can access it from a device that is connected by cable to router. It seems like either router randomly blocking wifi access to that rpi4 or rpi4 itself randomly decides to filter incoming connections.